# Returning multiple rows from querying XML column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `RDCAlerts` with the following data in a column of type `XML` called `AliasesValue`:

```
<aliases>
  <alias>
    <aliasType>AKA</aliasType>
    <aliasName>Pramod Singh</aliasName>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <aliasType>AKA</aliasType>
    <aliasName>Bijoy Bora</aliasName>
  </alias>
</aliases>
```

I would like to create a query that returns two rows - one for each alias and I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT
   AliasesValue.query('data(/aliases/alias/aliasType)'),
   AliasesValue.query('data(/aliases/alias/aliasName)'),
FROM [RdcAlerts]
```

but it returns just one row like this:

```
AKA AKA | Pramod Singh Bijoy Bora
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look at the .nodes() method in Books Online:

```
DECLARE @r TABLE (AliasesValue XML)
INSERT INTO @r 
SELECT '<aliases>   <alias>     <aliasType>AKA</aliasType>     <aliasName>Pramod Singh</aliasName>   </alias>   <alias>     <aliasType>AKA</aliasType>     <aliasName>Bijoy Bora</aliasName>   </alias> </aliases> '


SELECT c.query('data(aliasType)'), c.query('data(aliasName)')
FROM @r r CROSS APPLY AliasesValue.nodes('aliases/alias') x(c)
```

Comment: It's 5 years after you wrote your answer... and it's just helped me solve an issue I was having. Thanks!

Comment: The gift that keeps on giving!

Answer (score 21):

You need to use the `CROSS APPLY` statement along with the `.nodes()` function to get multiple rows returned.

```
select 
    a.alias.value('(aliasType/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as 'aliasType', 
    a.alias.value('(aliasName/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') as 'aliasName' 
from 
    RDCAlerts r
    cross apply r.AliasesValue.nodes('/aliases/alias') a(alias)
```