# Returning multiple rows from querying XML column in SQL Server (Revisited)

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes

The Answers to the Question [Returning multiple rows from querying XML column in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873192/returning-multiple-rows-from-querying-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008) were helpful. But I have an XML data set with a slightly different structure and need help getting valid query output.

Here's the code that demonstrates my problem.

```
DECLARE @XML_In XML = '
<ROOT>
  <PROCESS_RESULT>
    <CATEGORY>ABC</CATEGORY>
    <STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>
    <PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
      <MESSAGE_TEXT>ABC Process Category Error</MESSAGE_TEXT>
    </PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
  </PROCESS_RESULT>
  <PROCESS_RESULT>
    <CATEGORY>XYZ</CATEGORY>
    <STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>
    <PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
      <MESSAGE_TEXT>XYZ Process Category Error</MESSAGE_TEXT>
    </PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
  </PROCESS_RESULT>
</ROOT>'

DECLARE @XMLTab TABLE ( MyXMLTable XML)
INSERT INTO @XMLTab ( MyXMLTable ) VALUES( @XML_In )
SELECT MyXMLTable FROM @XMLTab

SELECT b.query('data(CATEGORY)')     AS CATEGORY
      ,b.query('data(STATUS)')       AS STATUS
      ,a.query('data(MESSAGE_TEXT)') AS MESSAGE_TEXT
FROM  @XMLTab
       CROSS APPLY 
       MyXMLTable.nodes('ROOT/PROCESS_RESULT/PROCESS_RESULT_MSG') x(a)
       CROSS APPLY
       MyXMLTable.nodes('ROOT/PROCESS_RESULT') y(b)
```

The two queries return the following outputs. The first is fine. The second is obviously incorrect.

[image]

How might I change the SELECT statement to accurately output the data, i.e., relating the MESSAGE_TEXT values to the proper CATEGORY and STATUS key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add another `CROSS APPLY` just to get a different level from the XML structure. Just specify the full path in the `.value()` function, relative to the path specified in the `.nodes()` function:

```sql
DECLARE @XML_In XML = '
<ROOT>
  <PROCESS_RESULT>
    <CATEGORY>ABC</CATEGORY>
    <STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>
    <PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
      <MESSAGE_TEXT>ABC Process Category Error</MESSAGE_TEXT>
    </PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
  </PROCESS_RESULT>
  <PROCESS_RESULT>
    <CATEGORY>XYZ</CATEGORY>
    <STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>
    <PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
      <MESSAGE_TEXT>XYZ Process Category Error</MESSAGE_TEXT>
    </PROCESS_RESULT_MSG>
  </PROCESS_RESULT>
</ROOT>'

DECLARE @XMLTab TABLE ( MyXMLTable XML)
INSERT INTO @XMLTab ( MyXMLTable ) VALUES( @XML_In )

SELECT tab.col.query('data(CATEGORY)')     AS [CATEGORY],
       tab.col.query('data(STATUS)')       AS [STATUS],
       tab.col.query('data(PROCESS_RESULT_MSG/MESSAGE_TEXT)') AS [MESSAGE_TEXT]
FROM  @XMLTab
       CROSS APPLY
       MyXMLTable.nodes('ROOT/PROCESS_RESULT') tab(col);
```

Returns:

```
CATEGORY    STATUS        MESSAGE_TEXT
---------   -----------   ------------
ABC         ERROR         ABC Process Category Error
XYZ         ERROR         XYZ Process Category Error
```

Also, when naming a result set field via `AS`, it is best to enclose it in square-brackets (as shown in the example code above).

Answer (score 0):

After a day of spinning my wheels on this problem, but in SQL 2014, a co-worker showed me this:

```
    DECLARE @XmlReportParameters NVARCHAR (MAX) = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <Name>Sri Patel</Name>
        <FavColors>
            <FavColor>Red</FavColor>
            <FavColor>Blue</FavColor>
            <FavColor>Green</FavColor>
        </FavColors>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
        <FavColors>
            <FavColor>Violet</FavColor>
            <FavColor>Mauve</FavColor>
        </FavColors>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
'

DECLARE @doc XML;
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE
(
    XmlColumn XML NULL
);

SET @doc = @XmlReportParameters;

INSERT INTO @XmlTable
    ( XmlColumn )
VALUES
    ( @doc )

-- Wrong Way
SELECT
    tbl.col.value('(Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')      AS CustomerName
   ,tbl.col.value('(FavColors/FavColor)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')       AS FavColor
FROM
    @XmlTable   xt
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/Customers/Customer') tbl(col);

-- Still wrong (but I'm not sure why)
SELECT
    tbl.col.value('(../Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')      AS CustomerName
   ,tbl.col.value('(FavColor)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')       AS FavColor
FROM
    @XmlTable   xt
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/Customers/Customer/FavColors') tbl(col);

-- Right Way
SELECT
    tbl.col.value('(../../Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')      AS CustomerName
   ,tbl.col.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')       AS FavColor
FROM
    @XmlTable   xt
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/Customers/Customer/FavColors/FavColor') tbl(col);
```

Returns:

```
CustomerName FavColor
------------ ----------
Sri Patel    Red
Jane Doe     Violet

CustomerName FavColor
------------ ----------
Sri Patel    Red
Jane Doe     Violet

CustomerName FavColor
------------ ----------
Sri Patel    Red
Sri Patel    Blue
Sri Patel    Green
Jane Doe     Violet
Jane Doe     Mauve
```

I didn't find anywhere else that told me I have to work "up" from the nodes path, I cannot work my way "down" to sub parts.

Comment: Sure this can (and should!) be done without `../../`! Moving *up* is not recommended. In most cases this is slow... The answer is to much for a comment. Just add a question yourself, place a link here and me (or somebody else) will pop up there to place an answer. The solution in short: hierarchically repeated calls to `.nodes()`

Comment: Thanks Shnugo!  I posted a question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950651/trouble-getting-xml-data-into-relational-format-in-sql-server-2014 for this.