# SQL XML Column - Cross Apply to Produce Multiple Rows based on XML 1 to many

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I've been studying this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873192/returning-multiple-rows-from-querying-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008), but I'm still not understanding the "cross apply" with XML data. Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498284/why-is-cross-apply-needed-when-using-xpath-queries).

I have an Xml column that contains a passenger, and the multiple flights and flight-legs on his ticket.

This is what I have working after much fiddling:

```
Select xmlDoc.value('(//Passenger[1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Passenger,
       XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('//FlightLeg') as xmlDoc2b
FROM xmlData as t 
CROSS APPLY 
    t.xmlDoc.nodes('//FlightLeg') AS XmlData2(xmlDoc2)
where xmlSchema = 'Reservation'
```

This is the current result.  The good news is that there are three rows which correspond to the number of FlightLegs. 
[image]

The data in each result is the same:

```
<FlightLeg seq="1">
  <FlightNumber>1849</FlightNumber>
  <DepartureAirport>MDW</DepartureAirport>
  <ArrivalAirport>STL</ArrivalAirport>
  <DepartureDateTime>2019-11-02T19:20:00</DepartureDateTime>
  <ArrivalDateTime>2019-11-02T20:25:00</ArrivalDateTime>
</FlightLeg>
<FlightLeg seq="2">
  <FlightNumber>2105</FlightNumber>
  <DepartureAirport>STL</DepartureAirport>
  <ArrivalAirport>OKC</ArrivalAirport>
  <DepartureDateTime>2019-11-02T21:25:00</DepartureDateTime>
  <ArrivalDateTime>2019-11-02T22:50:00</ArrivalDateTime>
</FlightLeg>
<FlightLeg seq="1">
  <FlightNumber>4565</FlightNumber>
  <DepartureAirport>OKC</DepartureAirport>
  <ArrivalAirport>MDW</ArrivalAirport>
  <DepartureDateTime>2019-11-04T11:10:00</DepartureDateTime>
  <ArrivalDateTime>2019-11-04T13:05:00</ArrivalDateTime>
</FlightLeg>
```

What I'm aiming for is each one for row 1 to have the first FlightLeg, row 2 the second, etc... Then after that I will pull out specific XML elements into columns.

Easier sample to reproduce:

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<Reservation><Name>Neal</Name><Flight>12</Flight><Flight>34</Flight><Flight>56</Flight></Reservation>';
DECLARE @xmlTable TABLE (
    xmlDoc Xml
);
Insert into @xmltable values (@xml)
Select xmlDoc from @XmlTable 

Select xmlDoc.value('(//Name[1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Passenger,
       XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('//Flight') as xmlDoc2b
FROM @xmlTable as t
CROSS APPLY 
    t.xmlDoc.nodes('//Flight') AS XmlData2(xmlDoc2)
```

I could see using some subscript here:

```
XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('//Flight[@xxxx]') as xmlDoc2b
```

but can't use RowNumber, would have to reset on each row from the table.

Now I'm trying to make my SQL look like the sample I found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5707/simple-way-to-import-xml-data-into-sql-server-with-tsql/):

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<Reservation><Name>Neal</Name><Flight>12</Flight><Flight>34</Flight><Flight>56</Flight></Reservation>';
DECLARE @xmlTable TABLE (
    xmlDoc Xml
);
Insert into @xmltable values (@xml)
--Select xmlDoc from @XmlTable 

-- This was running, but same data on all three rows 
Select xmlDoc.value('(//Name[1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Passenger,
       XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('//Flight') as xmlDoc2b

FROM @xmlTable as t
CROSS APPLY 
    t.xmlDoc.nodes('//Flight') AS XmlData2(xmlDoc2)


-- Trying to make above look like blog sample below 
Select xmlDoc.value('(//Name[1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Passenger,
       My_XML.FlightTest.query('//Flight') as FlightLegTest
FROM (SELECT xmlDoc 
      FROM @xmlTable as T(My_XML))
      CROSS APPLY My_XML.nodes('//Flight') AS My_XML (FlightTest) 
/* Sample from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5707/simple-way-to-import-xml-data-into-sql-server-with-tsql/ */ 
SELECT
   MY_XML.Customer.query('Name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\XMLClass\IntroSamples\BulkLoadCustomers1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('Customers/Customer') AS MY_XML (Customer);
```

I get error: Incorrect syntax near '(' 
where the line# points to this row: 
      FROM @xmlTable as T(My_XML))

So far I can't figure out why we put "as x(y)", in other words a second value in parentheses; I'm still researching that.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

Comment: `XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('//Flight')` should be something like `XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('.')` or `XmlData2.xmlDoc2.value('.', 'int')` presumably

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's it.  Then I get get "./FlightNumber" from there.  So when not using the ".", it starts at the root of the whole document.  I still find this confusing.  Put in answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CROSS APPLY 
    t.xmlDoc.nodes('//Flight') AS XmlData2(xmlDoc2)
```

Produces three rows where the context node is already set to the three Flights in turn. You just need to use `.` to access it.

For example `XmlData2.xmlDoc2.query('.')` or `XmlData2.xmlDoc2.value('.', 'int')` [as in this db <> fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17af7e3c9f344c50075f57b464229baf)

Comment: Great, got it!  Now I'm trying 3 levels of hierarchy, and getting too many rows back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008546/xml-column-three-levels-hierarchy-with-cross-apply